# Java + Hibernate - Print query with values to console

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I want to print sql queries generated by hibernate to console.

```
insert into ORDERS (CRETN_DT, CRETN_USER_ID, LAST_UPDT_DT, LAST_UPDT_USER_ID, ORDER_ID) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

This is what I see on console. Instead of ? , is it possible to print the actual value? Instead of printing the parameter values below the query , i would like to replace the ?s with the actual value which can be executed as is against the db.

Comment: this will generate the query and the parameters no?

Comment: Thanks for the link. However I would like the ?s to be replaced with actual value. The approaches listed seem to list the parameters below the query.

Comment: That is probably because it is not possible. For most database drivers, the query is prepared with those parameter placeholders, and the values are always sent separately. There never is a query with those values within the query instead of the parameter values, so most tools don't try to generate that because it is not very useful (error-prone, extra code maintenance, a query generated that way may not actually be valid for the targeted database,etc).

Comment: Try logback. In the logback.xml use next settings, to log hibernate bind values : <logger name="org.hibernate.type" level="TRACE" /> 
  <logger name="org.hibernate" level="DEBUG" />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [datasource-proxy](https://github.com/ttddyy/datasource-proxy) or [p6spy](https://github.com/p6spy/p6spy)

This allows you to view the actual parameter values used in firing the SQL. Example on how to configure can be found [here](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-log-jdbc-statements/)

Sample format would be as below:

> Name:DATA_SOURCE_PROXY, Time:6, Success:True, 
>   Type:Prepared, Batch:True, QuerySize:1, BatchSize:3, 
>   Query:["insert into post (title, version, id) values (?, ?, ?)"], 
>   Params:[(Post no. 0, 0, 0), (Post no. 1, 0, 1), (Post no. 2, 0, 2)

Comment: Thanks @Madhusudana